# Set password to access postfix running on macos

Tags: smtp-auth

I have configured postfix to act as a relay on my Mac Laptop.
I want to now enforce an authentication on postfix so that any client trying to connect on port 25 needs to authenticate first. Is this possible?

Comment: The tag wiki for *postfix-mta* says in **ALL CAPS** that questions related to administration are off-topic here. Please read the descriptions of all tags before using them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. You can use SASL to achieve this function. On Mac, install `cyrus-sasl` and modify the following settings in the Postfix configuration file to enable SMTP authentication and restrict relay access:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/login_maps
```

You also have to create a file at `/etc/postfix/login_maps` and add entries for the authenticated users. This file maps email addresses to usernames and passwords. Each line should be in the format:

```
user1@example.com password1
user2@example.com password2
```

Then generate hashed database file using:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/login_maps
```

After making these changes, restart the Postfix service to apply.

Comment: This question is off topic. Please don't spend time answering off-topic questions since it encourages others to ask similar questions, and the question will probably be deleted before long.